# Custom ID not reflecting in MUI DialogTitle component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

Edit: It's an issue in the library itself. Issue has been raised https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/36108

I want to assign a custom `id` to the `<DialogTitle />` component of MUI.

But no matter what `id` we give it always take from `aria-labelledby` and put it under id of `<DialogTitle />` component. And if we don't pass `aria-labelledby` then it takes some random `id` from MUI.

Could anyone tell me how to add a custom `id` to the `<DialogTitle />` component ?

[image]

```js
<Dialog
  fullScreen={fullScreen}
  open={open}
  onClose={handleClose}
  aria-labelledby="responsive-dialog-title"
>
  <DialogTitle id="test-custom-id">
    {"Use Google's location service?"}
  </DialogTitle>
</Dialog
```

[image: Edit]

Answer (score 0):

I see only two options here:

1. Wrap your `<Dialog />` with `<Box id='my-custom-id' />`
2. Add to `<Dialog testId='my-custom-id' />`

Comment: I want `id` in the `<DialogTitle />` component

Answer (score 0):

The value of the attribute `aria-labelledby` should be the same as your custom id. [Updated example](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-fast-47bbed?file=/demo.js).

Comment: But why should be `aria-labelledby` mandatory at the first place ? If I remove it, then it starts taking random mui id.

Comment: @Kundan I guess it ensures that the control is accessible to screen readers.

Comment: I agree but it should work without it as well. Same way it's working for other components.

Comment: The question is not about adding ARIA role, it's about adding `id`. Adding ARIA labels are not mandatory.

Comment: @Kundan my bad that link was from an old fork of the repo, the actual source for the Dialog element should be [this](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/Dialog/Dialog.js). If you need the ability to specify an id without `aria-labelledby` you'll probably have to create your own custom component.

Comment: Why it woks for other components then ? Without adding ARIA label. Seems like a issue in the library code itself.

Comment: @Kundan I can't answer for decisions made by the library's author. They've discussed it [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/9158). Your best bet is opening an issue on the repo and asking them directly why.

Comment: ok, fine. Will ask them.

Comment: @Kundan still not sure what the problem with adding the same value to `aria-labelledby` is, since it solves your issue :) Next time be more specific in your question.

Comment: I don't know how much you know about ARIA labels. But it's not good to have ARIA labels same as id. What if someone is following some random logic for naming their ids. Aria labels should be meaningful in the other place. It's not just about solving an problem, it's about solving in a correct way. But thanks, I would be more specific from next time though I tried being so. And JFYI, this is issue in the library itself.

Comment: @Kundan that's not an aria-label though that's [aria-labelledby](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-labelledby) which takes an id as reference. I don't know what 'following some random logic for naming their ids' means but ids should be unique, and even if randomly generated you can follow the same logic to populate the `aria-labelledby` value.